# .mdf equivalent for mysql (TOAD)

Tags: mysql, sql, toad, recovery

What is 'SQL Server Database Primary Data File (.mdf)' equivalent for mysql.

- I am using 'Toad for mysql' (Vesion 7.7) tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using `MyISAM` engine it should be `*.myd` extension file which corresponds to data file and `*.frm` corresponds to table format file.

Per [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/frm-file-format.html)

> Regardless of the storage engine you choose, every MySQL table you
>   create is represented on disk by a `.frm` file that describes the
>   table's format (that is, the table definition). The file bears the
>   same name as the table, with an .frm extension. The .frm format is the
>   same on all platforms, but in the description of the .frm format that
>   follows, the examples come from tables created under the Linux
>   operating system.

Comment: Thank for quick response Rahul. what about my stored procedures and  indexes?

Comment: @Munavvar, consider going through the mysql document link attached in answer.

Comment: already looked into that but not helpful. Thats why I ask this question here.

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL comes with an extendable table engine model, there is no straight answer to this question, since each table engine has different file formats.

The only file type that is independent of table engines, is the table definition file (*.frm).

Actual data and indexes are stored by different table engines in different ways. Even within a single table engine, there may be different ways to store data (e.g. in innodb the data can be stored in large tablespace files, or each table may have its own files). You have to check out each storage engine's own documentation on how it stores the data.

Much of the metadata is stored in the [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/system-database.html) system database, which is a myisam database. The other metadata schemas (information_schema, performance, sys) are constructed on-the-fly by MySQL as temporary memory tables (you can check with `show create table` command).

Some of